# Create an annotation of the whole document with JAPE

Tags: gate

I have a GATE document with a string like that:

```
The running back Ezekiel Elliott sprinted and rumbled etc.
```

I want to annotate this whole string with a *text* annotation. I'm looking for a JAPE rule but really don't know how to annotate the whole document using the start and end of the string like that:
[image]

Comment: It's also possible to do it by creating a new GATE PR and using this JAVA code:  `AnnotationSet inputAs = document.getAnnotations(inputASName);
  AnnotationSet outputAs = document.getAnnotations(outputASName);
long startOffset = inputAs.firstNode().getOffset();
long endOffset = inputAs.lastNode().getOffset();

try {
     outputAs.add(startOffset,endOffset,"Tweet", features);
  } catch (InvalidOffsetException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }`

Comment: But if you use `long startOffset = inputAs.firstNode().getOffset(); long endOffset = inputAs.lastNode().getOffset();` then the output would be dependent on the content of `inputAs`. It will **not annotate the whole document** but the whole `inputAs` only. And it fails for `NullPointerException` when the `inputAs` is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not recommend using JAPE for this task, because there are no input annotations to start with. But you can do it easily with [Groovy scripting PR](https://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:api:groovy:pr)

```
outputAS.add(0L, doc.content.size(), "Text", gate.Utils.featureMap())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `doc.getFeatures().put()` method to add new features to a document. For example, below lines of code give a field `category` and `score` for the document.

```
doc.getFeatures().put("category","fiction");
doc.getFeatures().put("score",13);
```

Refer to this slide set. It tells us how to use JAPE to use document features.

https://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-may11/track-3/module-10-advanced-ie/module-10-advanced-ie.pdf

Comment: This is not the answer of my question. This response provides new features for the document but what I need is to add annotation to the document.